# Angular Universal TransferHttpCacheModule is not working inside a route on router navigation, only after reload

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-httpclient, angular-transfer-state

I have an Universal app with `TransferHttpCacheModule` addet to `app.module.ts` like that:

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'serverApp' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the routes implementation:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent },
  { path: 'ssr-test', component: HttpExampleComponent },
  ...
];
```

in the `app.component.html` I add a navigation link to reach the `ssr-test` path

```html
    <li>
      <a
        routerLink="/ssr-test"
        routerLinkActive="activebutton"
        ariaCurrentWhenActive="page"
        >SSR test</a
      >
    </li>
```

the `HttpExampleComponent` template contains a `<app-list></app-list>` child that performs a `GET` call on component init:

```js
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  list?: Products[];

  constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadList();
  }

  loadList(): void {
    this.apiClient.getList().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.list = data;
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

when I navigate to the `ssr-path` route, the page is show correctly, but the `<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">` tag is not present in the page source and the `GET` call is executed

if I reload the page the `<script>` is present and the `GET` call is not executed, but I expect the data to be present without reloading the page and no `GET` call to be executed

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

The `TransferHttpCacheModule` installs an Http interceptor that avoids duplicate `HttpClient` GET requests on the client, for requests that were already made when the application was rendered on the server side.

This is true until the app has stabilized :

```
export class TransferHttpCacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef, private transferState: TransferState) {
    // Stop using the cache if the application has stabilized, indicating initial rendering is
    // complete.
    appRef.isStable
      .pipe(
        filter((isStable) => isStable),
        take(1),
        tap(() => (this.isCacheActive = false)),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
  ...
}
```

[transfer-http-cache.interceptor.ts in the source code](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/modules/common/clover/src/transfer-http-cache/transfer-http-cache.interceptor.ts)